# VBA - Solver Macro with Relative References

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I need to use the Excel Solver several times in a worksheet. Each scenario that I need to utilize the solver for has the same formatting so I'd like to use a macro with relative references to allow me to run the solver without setting the problem up each time. I have the following code but the ByChange argument for the SolverOk function is giving me an error.

```
Sub solverMacro()

SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:= _
        Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 0)), _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 0), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 0), Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0), Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0), Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0), Relation:=3, FormulaText:=ActiveCell.Offset(-9, 0)
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0), Relation:=3, FormulaText:=ActiveCell.Offset(-9, 0)
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0), Relation:=3, FormulaText:=ActiveCell.Offset(-9, 0)
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(6, 0), Relation:=3, FormulaText:=ActiveCell.Offset(-9, 0)
    SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:= _
        Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 0)),     _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:= _
        Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 0)),     _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve

End Sub
```

I see a lot of similar examples on various websites but ALL of them use absolute references, at least for the ByChange argument. Is there a correct way to get the ByChange argument to accept relative references?

Comment: I understand that my comments finds you a little late.. Could you try to fully qualify your ranges? That is, instead of `Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 0))` use `Sheet1.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 0))` (you will have to change `Sheet1` accordingly). Do you have two `SolverOK` calls?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

" I'd like to use a macro with relative references to allow me to run the solver without setting the problem up each time" - you dont need to use relative references only for that purpose. Is this code recorded or punched in by you?

Comment: I recorded the macro once and then replaced the cell references with calls to ActiveCell.Offset. When I did that I got an error on this line: ByChange:= Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 0)). How can I use the macro in various locations in a worksheet without using relative references?

Comment: you can construct cell references using row and column counters. Something like this                                            SolverAdd CellRef:="$BA$" & i, Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"